# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException during left-shift operation on Array

Tags: java, arrays, exception, data-structures, indexoutofboundsexception

This is the code which I tried to perform Array Left shift operation which works fine for a few inputs but as i am increasing the shift amount it gives an **ArrayOutOfBoundException exception**.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayShift {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x,y;
    int[] n = new int[10];
    int temp = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //x is size of array
    x = sc.nextInt();
    // y is the amount of shift
    y = sc.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0;i<x;i++)
    {
        n[i] = sc.nextInt();

    }
    //Outer forloop for shift amount = y
    for(int k = 0;k<y;k++)
    {
    temp = n[0];

    //Inner forloop for shift amount = 1  
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {   

        n[i] = n[i+1];


    }
    n[x-1]=temp;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    System.out.print(n[i]+" ");
  }
  }
```

Output

```
20 10
41 73 89 7 10 1 59 58 84 77 77 97 58 1 86 58 26 10 86 51
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
at ArrayShift.main(ArrayShift.java:14)
```

Comment: You have a comment saying "x is size of array" but it doesn't look like it: `int[] n = new int[10];`

Comment: You're most likely setting x as a value that's bigger than length 10, hence the loop goes out of bounds.

Comment: Ohh damn!! can't believe it was such a silly mistake..really sorry

Answer (score 0):

You are already declaring the size of the array as 10 in this statement:`int[] n = new int[10];`

which means even if you enter x value as 100 the value of the array size will still be 10. hence the Array Index out of bound exception